Collating Excel files
At my current job, every month we get sales data sent from 9 regions of the country - these come in as Excel Worksheets containing 5 sheets each. We have have to go through the tedious manual labour of copying thousands of rows from every sheet in worksheets and pasting it into a single 'master worksheet'. I dont need to mention that this is time inefficient and prone to human error.
I know this process can be sped up using the 'Power Query' function in Excel but was wondering if there are ways to correct the output
I tried the Power Query function to combine the worksheet but there were formatting issues in the output

Are you looking for a correction of the PowerQuery results or do you want to explore other options outside of PowerQuery? Can you show, by editing your question, what you are currently doing with PowerQuery and what are the formatting issues you're mentioning?

"...there were formatting issues in the output" What formatting issues? please show us what you tried, what the current result is and what the desired result is.

I did this making links using a combination of indirect() and iferror().
